# Prevent form submission if there is errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, var

Basically i have a code that shows the user an error if the ID he wrote already exist or is too short but the problem is i can't figure out how to prevent the form from submission where there there is an error.

The code that needs to popup an alert window:

```
jQuery("#submit").click(function(e){

           if(error === '1')
           {
     alert("There are some errors in the form.");
     e.preventDefault();
           }
   });
```

Then i get the answer using AJAX and showing up the error:

```
if(msg == 'OK')
{
var error = '0';
}
else
{
var error = '1';
jQuery("#idCheck_msg").slideDown("fast");
jQuery("#idCheck_text").text(msg).slideDown("fast");
}});
}
```

I have tried to do something with `var error` but Firebug says that error is not defined and the form get's submitted even when there is an error.

Any help? ;)

Comment: are u declaring the variable `error` before your `if` ?

Comment: nope, seems like i need to do it before AND outside of the AJAX response, totally confused about the way i should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `error` as a global variable. That is remove `var`before using the variable:

```
var error;
if(msg == 'OK')
{
    error = '0';
}
else
{
    error = '1';
...
```

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks buddy.

Comment: **Important:** Note that you need to _define_ the variable at the global level with `var`, then simply reference it without the `var` keyword.  Think of `var` like `CreateThis`.  Clearly when you just want to access/set it you don't need to use `var`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're setting the value of `error` **after** the form is submitted but checking it's value **before** the form is submitted.

Given the code in your post, `error` will be undefined when you attempt to check it's value. In addition, after the form is submitted, `error` will still be undefined because you're declaring it within the scope of your AJAX response handler using the `var` keyword.

If you remove the `var` keyword from your AJAX handler when setting the value of `error`, your submission logic should work the second time around.

**Bottom Line:** The value of `error` needs to be set **before** your form is submitted, not in the AJAX response handler.

Answer (score 0):

When is the AJAX call made? You won't be able to check 'error' until you get a success response from the AJAX call. Also you need to remove 'var' so it is in global scope.

If your AJAX call is also made when the form is submitted, you will need to move the error check to inside the code that handles the AJAX response.

Comment: It's made when one of the fields value is changed (like i said it checks if the ID already exist on `.change()`